# commutant of a non unital $C^*$ algebra

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

If $A$ is a non-unital $C^*$ algebra,is the commutant of $A$ empty?

Does there exist a theorem which states that every $C^*$ algebra has commutant(centralizer)?

Comment: How do you define the commutant? What's the commutant of $C[0,1]$? Do you mean the centre?

Comment: I mean $A'=\{x\in A,xa=ax ,\forall a \in A\}$

Comment: Yeah, that's the centre, and it's a terrible notation because it is standard to use $A'$ for the commutant of $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The centre $Z(A)$ of $A$ is never empty, because it always contains $0$.

It can be just $\{0\}$, though. Typical example would be $K(H)$. Since $K(H)'=\mathbb C I$, then 
$$
Z(K(H))=K(H)\cap K(H)'=\{0\}.
$$

Comment: Yes, more than you can imagine. For any locally compact Hausdorff space $X$, $C_0(X)$ is a commutative C$^*$-algebra. For a non-commutative example, take $A=M_2(\mathbb C)\oplus M_2(\mathbb C)$; then $Z(A)=\mathbb CI_2\oplus \mathbb CI_2$.